# Jest encountered an unexpected token - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I see there are a lot of questions around about this, but none of them are working for me.
I created my RN project with react-native init with typescript template.

So, this is my whole `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.2",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "swr": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@jest/create-cache-key-function": "^29.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native/@jest/create-cache-key-function": "^29.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
};
```

and this is my Error in the console:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/ilirbajrami/Desktop/MyApp/node_modules/@rneui/themed/dist/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { AirbnbRatingDefault as AirbnbRating, } from './AirbnbRating';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      2 | import React from 'react';
      3 | import {SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
    > 4 | import {Button} from '@rneui/themed';
        | ^
      5 | import Woman from '../../assets/Woman';
      6 | import {NavProps} from '../types/SvgTypes';
      7 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1449:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/screens/Login.tsx:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/screens/Login.test.tsx:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.689 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Any help would be appreciated and would save another whole day of dealing with this.